# Two y-axes in ggplot with faceting: eternal frustration

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm trying to make a faceted plot, where each 'facet' has two y-axes and two sets of data corresponding to them. I've read just about every post here about the double y-axis controversy, but in my field it is a very common way to display data and I just want to be able to make it work, damn it.

My data looks like this:

```
ShellNum   SampNum    AccDist d13C  d18O  Species  Age   Type Univ
1 290819-1 290819-1 1  137.41 2.37 -0.85 larensis 17.4 Fossil  UdN
2 290819-1 290819-1 2  132.41 2.42 -1.22 larensis 17.4 Fossil  UdN
3 290819-1 290819-1 3  127.41 2.78 -1.25 larensis 17.4 Fossil  UdN
4 290819-1 290819-1 4  120.71 3.05 -1.41 larensis 17.4 Fossil  UdN
5 290819-1 290819-1 5  114.01 2.86 -1.47 larensis 17.4 Fossil  UdN
6 290819-1 290819-1 6  107.31 2.81 -1.34 larensis 17.4 Fossil  UdN
```

I am faceting by ShellNum (there are 25 distinct values of it total over ~800 lines) I want to plot both the d18O and d13C values on two different axes (d18O on the right, d13C on the left). Preferably I want to set the limits of the axes manually, but for now I'm trying to work within sec_axis and just scale it.

Here's my code:

```
fossils.all <- ggplot(fossils, aes(x = AccDist)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = d18O)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = d18O)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = d13C), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = d13C), color = "blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-3, 0),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.+2*2, name = "d13C")) +
  facet_wrap( ~ ShellNum, ncol = 5) 
fossils.all
```

I get the following error:
"geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
adjust the group aesthetic?"

The second series of data (d13C) isn't even showing up on the plot right now. What do I do? Do I just give up and use base R?

Comment: *"set the limits of the axes manually"* ... I'm confident that your research is telling you this, but just in case: `sec_axis` only allows functional scaling. For as much effort as it appeared to take to convince the power to add that much functionality (as much as you and many others disagree), I doubt that true manual control is in the works.

Comment: Yes, I know. Just thought I'd state what I really, really want in case anyone had a work around to be able to actually do it. But I'm willing to work with sec_axis and the scaling for easiness' sake right now.

Comment: With this sample data, I get no errors. If I modify one of the `ShellNum` to be different, I get the *console message* about "only one observation", but that's not an error nor even a warning. It's just suggesting that you may be assuming that `ShellNum` is more interesting than the volume of data suggests. You can safely ignore it. (And even suppress it with `suppressMessages(print(fossils.all))`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, adding a secondary axis does not change how your data gets mapped; the positive numbers in `d13C` will still show up in the positive region of your primary y axis (and will be hidden if you constrain its limits to `c(-3, 0)`, unless you shift those values themselves.

Here, I shift down the `d13C` data by 4, and shift up the secondary axis scale by 4.

```
fossils.all <- ggplot(fossils, aes(x = AccDist)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = d18O)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = d18O)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = d13C-4), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = d13C-4), color = "blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-3, 0),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.+4, name = "d13C")) +
  facet_wrap( ~ ShellNum, ncol = 5) +
  theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "blue"))
fossils.all
```

[image]